# Fullcalendar - How do I load events while browsing?

Tags: fullcalendar

The idea is as follows:

When browsing the calendar I want to load the events. For example: I'm viewing the month of August so I want to download the data for the month of August.

Currently I load everything when entering the page, but it is taking too long!

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or alternatively https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function (same idea but with more flexibility). As explained there, fullCalendar will fetch events from the specified source automaticaly whenever it needs new data (usually because the user changed the dates on display). And when the calendar first loads it will just request data for the time period which is initially on show.

Comment: Of course, your server has to co-operate in this venture by only returning events relating to the period of time which fullCalendar sends it (via the start and end parameters).

Comment: does anyone have an example?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation links I gave you. Is there something specific from there which you don't understand? Please clarify what part of the process precisely you need help with.